# Unrecognized target bytecode. Compiling Java with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, spock, java-11

I saw couple of problems like this but none of the given advice helped me, so I add this.
I have Java app and I migrate it to Java 11. I can run it but when i try to `mvn install` it i get tge error:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests (default)
> on project osa-backend: Execution default of goal
> org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests failed:
> Unrecognized target bytecode.

This is my plugin:

> ```
>         <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
>         <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>1.6</version>
>         <executions>
>             <execution>
>                 <goals>
>                     <goal>compileTests</goal>
>                 </goals>
>             </execution>
>         </executions>
>         <dependencies>
>             <dependency>
>                 <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
>                 <version>2.4.16</version>
>             </dependency>
>         </dependencies>
>     </plugin>
> ```

Thanks for any suggestions cause I have no idea what can I change now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817147/compiling-java-and-groovy-with-java-11

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with no luck.

Comment: why groovy 2.4 with java 11 ? groovy 2.4 is not working correctly even with java 9 :http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html

Comment: Besides (and because you also tagged the question with _spock_), the current version Spock 2.0-M4 needs Groovy 2.5 as minimum and the previous stable release 1.3 also supports Groovy 2.5 if you use the right artifact. There is no need to stay on 2.4 because of Spock, if that is what you thought.

Answer (score 0):

This message is to warn you that your desired bytecode is not supported by the versions you currently have.

Targeting Java 11 bytecode requires Groovy 2.5.3/3.0.0-alpha-4 or newer and GMavenPlus 1.6.2 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case bumping the version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` from `3.8.1` to `3.10.1` solved the issue, every other approach suggested in similar threads failed :

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.1</version>
   <configuration>
   <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where `${maven.compiler.release}` = your java version

Comment: nb. using Groovy ver 3.0.15